# Need to find module of magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, velocity, conductors

I have a post-lab problem
During the experiments I have a U magnet on a scale. Inside the U magnet there is a conductor with a steady current. The conductor is made so that the magnetic field is uniform . At each .4 A the scale gives me the added mass to the tared system.
So I have the current, I also have the length of the conductor and the mass so the force.

I need to find a way to have the module of the magnetic field. I guess its with F= q*v*B
Although I am wondering how can i find my velocity with the current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force on a current carrying wire is given by: 
$$d\vec F= I d \vec l \times \vec B$$
Or for a uniform current and field and in scalar form:
$$F=BIl$$
If you want to derive this from $$F=qvB$$ then you can note that in a time $t$ a total charge of $\frac{q}{L} vt$ passes through a point in your conductor. Since current is charge per unit time we have:
$$I=\frac{q}{L}v$$

Comment: Okay I will try that thanks I'm completing it tonight!